# Recoding in R: Transform 2 numeric rows of data into one factor row

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data frame:

```
> x = data.frame(var1 = c(0,0,1,1), var = c(0,1,0,1))
```

I would like to add another column to that data frame that is factor, set based on the values of var1 and var2.

```
factor "00" if both are 0 
factor "10" if var1 = 1 and var2 = 0
factor "01" if var1 = 0 and var2 = 1
factor "11" if both are 1
```

In reality I have about 10 variables and need the factors to generate cross-tables to check how other variables are influence by factors.

I could write if statements to get this done, however I think there must be a smarter way of doing that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `interaction`:

```
 transform(x, Factor=interaction(var1, var,sep=''))

  var1 var Factor
1    0   0     00
2    0   1     01
3    1   0     10
4    1   1     11
```

Comment: I still think creating a new named column with `x$Factor = interaction(x$var1, x$var, sep='') ` is better practice - more concise, explicit about which things we are working on and so immune to typos and scope problems. The `transform` function is just a bit needless here. $0.02

Comment: @Spacedman Well. I agree even I use it for is syntax sugar but what is the $0.02 in your comment? the cost in dollar of using `transform`? :)

Comment: Its just my "two cents worth" - an American expression for saying I'm just adding a little bit that's probably a minor contribution. I'm not even American (should be £0.02p, I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform` and `paste0`

```
> x <- transform(x, Factor=paste0(var1, var))
  var1 var Factor
1    0   0     00
2    0   1     01
3    1   0     10
4    1   1     11

> sapply(x, class) # checking class for each column
     var1       var    Factor 
"numeric" "numeric"  "factor"
```

Another alternative is using `within`

```
x <- within(x, Factor <- factor(paste0(var1, var)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new column - use `factor` and `paste0`:

```
> x$f = factor(paste0(x$var1,x$var))
> x
  var1 var  f
1    0   0 00
2    0   1 01
3    1   0 10
4    1   1 11
```